# Text color gradient in textview not working

Tags: android, textview, linear-gradients

I want to set gradient text color in my `TextView`. I have used this code for it

```
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20, new int[]{Color.rgb(225, 225, 225),Color.rgb(150, 150, 150)}, new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
text.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

When activity is launched, the text is not shown. But if I change the orientation of my phone, then it will display the text in `TextView` with gradient color. I have tested it on HTC One V. It is working fine on emulator and Samsung device.

I have also tested the following example, and the same problem occur .

https://github.com/koush/Widgets

Comment: did you call `text.invalidate();` after setting the shader?

Answer (score -3):

```
.text1 {    background: #dfdfdf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d1d1d1 0%, #000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d1d1d1), color-stop(100%,#000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d1d1d1 0%,#000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d1d1d1 0%,#000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d1d1d1 0%,#000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d1d1d1 0%,#000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d1d1d1', endColorstr='#000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-animation-name: masked-animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
h1{color:#f00;}


<div class="text1"><h1>Lorem</h1></div>
```

Comment: it's working please check in a safari. As usually all mobile device are supporting chrome and safri.

Comment: This is not related to android!